# golang all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock, channel

I got an error when running follow golang snippet. 
I think the progress will block at wg.Wait() until the go routine is over. then the value would be obtained from c1. But it may not proceed as expected.

```
func main() {

c1 := make(chan string)
//var c1 chan string
var wg sync.WaitGroup

wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("go routine begin\n")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    c1 <- "one"
    fmt.Printf("go routine done\n")
}()
wg.Wait()
fmt.Printf("done c1: %v\n", <-c1)
fmt.Printf("out\n")
}
```

the error info is,

```
 go routine begin
 fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Answer (score 1):

The write to `c1` will never execute, because the read from `c1` is after `wg.Wait()`, which will stop until `c1` is written to. So main goroutine waits at `wg.Wait()` and the nested goroutine waits at `c1` write.

You can make the channel buffered, or wait for `c1` read on a separate goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

In Golang write operations on an unbuffered channel are blocking. It's clear from the documentation.

Your execution is blocked at

```
c1 <- "one"
```

The deferred statement

```
defer wg.Done()
```

never executes.

Answer (score 0):

In your code,you are using an unbuffered channel which blocks until "one" is received by a receiver. In this case, the code doesn't go past wg.Wait() beacause wg.Done() never gets executed.

I think this is what you are after.

```
func main() {

c1 := make(chan string)
//var c1 chan string

go func() {
    fmt.Printf("go routine begin\n")
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    c1 <- "one"
    fmt.Printf("go routine done\n")
}()
fmt.Printf("done c1: %v\n", <-c1)
fmt.Printf("out\n")
}
```